# what is the exact meaning and function of "も" in below sentence?

Tags: particles

The sentence is "ムダっていわなくても " I know the total meaning is"I wouldn’t say that is useless" but I want to know the exact meaning and function of "も" in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It's a part of [ても/でも meaning "even if"](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82-temo-meaning/). So the literal translation of ムダっていわなくても is "even if you don't say (it's a) waste...". As usual, the final part of the sentence has been omitted, but it's usually (ムダって言わなくても)**いい**. Thus the sentence roughly means "You don't have to say (it's a) waste".

Depending on the context, this sentence implies something like this:

- I know it's a waste, so you don't have to say that to me! I'm doing this on purpose!
- It may be a waste, but saying that without reservation is too harsh!